# Get Value at Specific Index using Row and Column

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two values:

```
private ArrayList<DataEntry> data;
private String title;
```

Within class `DataEntry` is:

```
private int nRow, nCol;
private double[] data;
```

I have to return the value of the item at the given `row` and `column` (if any), `null` otherwise using the function below:

```
public Double get(int row, int column) { }
```

I understand that the formula: `data[(row * numberOfColumns) + Columns]` provides the index in a normal array that is not 2d but I am not sure how to do this for `an ArrayList`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's almost the exact same for ArrayList, just use the `.get` syntax: `data.get((row * numberOfColumns) + Columns)`

Essentially you can think of `.get(int index)` as equivalent to the array subscript `[index]` notation for indexing purposes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

However, there are some caveats, for example you can get `null` with ArrayList, since it is a collection of objects

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but how exactly would you find the number of columns in an array list if it has not been defined?